# 301 redirect not working for sub folders or pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've looked through dozens of threads and sites but I can;t seem to find a solution to this problem, I'm probably missing something obvious.

My dev site has been indexed somehow by my robots file having a typo in it. So I added a 301 redirect to my .htaccess file and removes everything else so the .htaccess file includes only the following:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 / http://live_site.com/
```

This works fine for the homepage. But any sub folders redirect without a / after the .com

So i get http://live_site.comsubfolder instead of http://live_site.com/subfolder

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.*)$ http://live_site.com/$1
```

Comment: Again, causes the same problem, don't suppose this could be  server config problem?

Comment: Is there any other `.htaccess` somewhere in your system?

Comment: No other htaccess for this cpanel account. I can't fin anyone with this issue, now I can't even replicate it, getting a 500 error and if i go to some urls i get the url i types in followed by the new_site.html/ repeated about 1000 times afterwards.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo and I just fixed it. Try it now. Also let me know if `live_site.com` and `oldsite.com` are on 2 different hosts or same host?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing using this .htaccess configuration.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```